# codeigniter 3.1.11 dynamic url with route but showing 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem regarding routes on `CI 3.1.11`, here's what I want to happen:

url: http://myurl.local/1/settings/company/
url: http://myurl.local/1/settings/company/detial

The **1** is an **ID**, then **settings** is a dir, **company** is the controller and **detail** is a function. I just want to make the segment(1) or the ID as a dynamic value, but the routes will show me `404`. :( help me with this, please.

here's what i did to my route:

`$route['([A-Za-z0-9_.])+/(:any)'] = "$2";`

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> You should mention the controller and method name in routes as follows

`$route['([A-Za-z0-9_.])+/(:any)'] = "Controller/method/$2";`

Comment: Hello @boominathan, thanks for the response but  i want my url or segments to be dynamic. Like i could change to :

`12/post/details/`
`10/admin/console`

So i need a route that could do like that.